# Add block for category and subcategories

Tags: category, layout, blocks, magento-1

I need to add my *.phtml page to right part of the site in special category and subcategories.

I tried `<catalog_category_view>`, but it is for all categories. I also tried `<CATEGORY_{category_id}>` but it is not working (do not know why) and i think it will not be for subcategories.

So, how may i do it? where should i paste this code:

```
 <reference name="right">
            <block type="my_module/block" name="blog.articles"
                   as="blog.articles"
                   template="path/to.phtml"
                   translate="label">
                <label>Articles</label>
            </block>
        </reference>
```

Comment: <reference name="right">
            <block type="tsg_widgetblog/widgetblog" name="blog.articles"
                   as="blog.articles"
                   template="widgetblog/portalcatalog/articles.phtml"
                   translate="label">
                <label>Articles</label>
            </block>
        </reference>

Comment: Try with custom layout update part in those categories.

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVED: I created my own handle. I wrote an observer for `controller_action_layout_load_before` and added my handle after the following condition:

```
if (strpos(Mage::registry('current_category')->getPath(), '{category_id}'))
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. It would be great if you also added the code that adds the layout handle. Keep in mind that you can accept your own answer after 2 days.